# OSError: [WinError 126] while importing seaborn package

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

I got an example project from my friend that uses seaborn package to draw maps. I've opened project in pycharm, created venv, installed all needed packages and tried to run his code. Unfortunately code returns an error while importing package seaborn:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Carlito/Desktop/Maps/map.py", line 6, in <module>
    from seaborn import set
  File "C:\Users\Carlito\Desktop\Maps\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .rcmod import *
  File "C:\Users\Carlito\Desktop\Maps\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\rcmod.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import palettes, _orig_rc_params
  File "C:\Users\Carlito\Desktop\Maps\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\palettes.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .utils import desaturate, set_hls_values, get_color_cycle
  File "C:\Users\Carlito\Desktop\Maps\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py", line 6, in <module>
    from scipy import stats
  File "C:\Users\Carlito\Desktop\Maps\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 136, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\Carlito\Desktop\Maps\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\_distributor_init.py", line 61, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126]
```

I have tried manually installing all dependencies of this package but it didn't work. These are packages that I've installed:
[image]

One maybe important detail, my friend uses Linux Mint, while I am trying to run the project on Windows 10.
Anyone knows what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

More info required, give this a try

Check for paths hardcoded and try changing to windows backslashes

Example
Here the filepath is given `C:/Users/Carlito/Desktop/Maps/map.py`, which is Linux , try

Windows

```
C:\Users\Carlito\Desktop\Maps\map.py
C:\\Users\\Carlito\\Desktop\\Maps\\map.py
```